# Clarification on "ifcase" syntax

Tags: conditionals

I am quite new to LaTeX and have been using it mostly to write up my assignments. I have since taken on the challenge to re-write my resume using LaTeX too and I have grown quite fond of the twentyseondscv template, which can be found [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv).

The template is mostly quite user-friendly, even for a novice like myself, but I have an issue understanding a small part of the code - the resume alternates the colour of the section header between grey and blue (starting with grey) and I replicate the portion of the code that does this below:

```
% Command to create the rounded boxes around the section titles
\newcommand*\round[2]{
    \tikz[baseline = (char.base)]\node[rectangle, rounded corners, fill=#2, text = white](char){#1};
}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{
    {
        \round{#1}{
            \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
            maingray\or
            mainblue\or
            maingray\or
            mainblue\or
            maingray\or
            mainblue\or
            maingray\or
            mainblue\or
            maingray\or
            mainblue\else
            maingray\fi
        }
    }
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {
        \color{gray}
        \Large\sectioncolor{#1}
    }
}
```

I just have a few queries about the `ifcase` syntax and I was unable to find any documentation on it so I thought to ask here.

1. Why is there a need for the % in `\ifcase\value{colorCounter}%`? I thought % is used in LaTeX to comment out something? However, I realised that when I remove the %, the code does not work and I get an error saying something like "maingray is not defined". Here, maingray and mainblue are simply colours that were defined higher up in the code (which I have not shown).
2. What does the `\fi` portion of the `\ifcase` syntax do/stand for?
3. I noticed that the `\ifcase` code has only 6 "maingrays" and 5 "mainblues". Does this mean that, hypothetically, if I have a 12th section, the colour of this 12th section header will break the alternating pattern i.e it will be in grey and not blue (as it is supposed to be)?

My apologies if these queries are trivial but I would greatly appreciate anyone who can answer them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it is commenting out a space, try typesetting

```
hello%
world
```

compared to

```
hello
world
```

in the code you show without the `%` it would end up calling `\color{ maingray}` and tell you that colour name starting with a space is undefined.

2. `\fi`  (if backwards) ends the `\ifcase` so here as the last segment is an `\else` clause all numbers greater than the list given wil use the final value.
3. yes as noted above this is using `\else` so any value above the list given will generate `maingray`

If you want it to alternate gray/blue it would be simpler to have used `\ifodd` rather than `\ifcase`, such as:

```
main\ifodd\value{colorCounter}gray\else blue\fi
```

There are multiple other missing `%` eg

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {
        \color{gray}
        \Large\sectioncolor{#1}
    }
}
```

is

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{SPACE{SPACE\color{gray}IGNOREDSPACE\Large\sectioncolor{#1}SPACE}SPACE}
```

so adding multiple space tokens (and removing all of LaTeX's normal section heading features such as preventing page breaks just after a heading)

Comment: Right! I deleted my comment because I was still trying to figure out why my version of `\ifodd` was not working. Thank you for the edit! Your code does work, but I do have a few more queries regarding it. Why is the syntax `main\ifodd\value{colorCounter}gray\else blue\fi` and not `\ifodd\value{colorCounter}maingray\else blue\fi`? I mean like, why do we "split up" maingray? Is this just how the syntax is supposed to be? Also, how come we can just write `blue` instead of `mainblue`? In fact, I realise when I write `mainblue` instead of `blue`, the code does not work...

Comment: @EthanMark I just pulled out the common part your two colors are maingray and mainblue so you could do \ifodd.. maingray\else mainblue\fi but that means writing main twice so you can write it as main\ifodd.. gray\else blue\fi and only have the conditional around the bit that is different in each branch

Comment: Oh wow! I see now! So you basically "factored out" main (like as if it is mathematics)! I did not know you could do that to code as well. That is very cool. Thank you for the clarifications :)

Comment: What if I want only blue colored blocks? I am new to LateX, and I am trying to use the same template for a Resume.